# How to get filtered Laravel relationship models?

Tags: laravel

is it possible in Laravel 8.0 to get filtered relationship models?

Example: In the controller I have

```
 $thread = Thread::find(1);

 // example logic between getting the thread and passing to JsonResponse
 $thread->messages = $thread->messages->filter(function (Message $message) {
     return $message->type_id === 3;
 });

 return new JsonResponse($thread);
```

Thanks to call `$thread->messages` I have lazy loaded messages in the response, but it lazy load all messages that belongs to that thread and I just want to get filtered ones.
How can I achive that?

Thread model

```
public function messages(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
}
```

Message model

```
public function type(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(MessageType::class, 'id', 'type_id');
}
```

Comment: Using a scope might be interesting here as well: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: @PeterKrebs how would you do that? In the documenation I can only see the example where scope is declared and called from the same model (scopePopular method is declared in the User model and then User::popular()->get()). In my case I have Thread model but scope would be declared in the Message model.

Comment: I found this tutorial. Check the "Scope with relationship" part: https://medium.com/@janaksan_/using-scope-with-laravel-7c80dd6a2c3d

Comment: This tutorial shows how to get $category and $activePosts separatelly, but I need $category with loaded $activePosts

Comment: You can call scopes with a parameter, which would help reduce duplicated code. Just an Idea, I don't have time for a full answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a Closure to the `load` method to lazy load them.

```php
$thread = Thread::find(1);

$thread->load(['messages' => function ($message) {
    return $message->where('type_id', 3);
}]);

return new JsonResponse($thread);
```

or do the same using the `with` method.

```php
$thread = Thread::with(['messages' => function ($message) {
    return $message->where('type_id', 3);
}])->find(1);

return new JsonResponse($thread);
```

---

Short-hand Closure (PHP version >= 7.4)

```php
$thread = Thread::with(['messages' => fn ($m) => $m->where('type_id', 3)])->find(1);
```

```
$thread = Thread::find(1);

$thread->load(['messages' => fn ($m) => $m->where('type_id', 3)]);
```

---

Separate relationship

```php
# Thread model
// or whatever name makes sense in your application
public function active_messages() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class)->where('type_id', 3);
}
```

```php
$thread = Thread::with('active_messages')->find(1);
```

```php
$thread = Thread::find(1);

$thread->load('active_messages');
```

---

In terms of queries, all options are the same.

Comment: Since PHP 7 is EOL, it's cleaner (IMO) to use arrow functions like this: `$thread->load(['messages' => fn ($message) => $message->where('type_id', 3)]);`

Comment: It is. But you'd be surprised how many places still use php5 :(

Comment: @IGP thanks for the answer. It works! Does it mean that in every places that I need to filter these messages I need to pass a Closure? Is there a way to avoid duplicated code?

Comment: IF you find yourself having to apply the same filter over and over, you could make it it's own relationship ( `return $this->hasMany(Message::class)->where('type_id', 3);`. ) and then lazy/eager load that. Another option is using short-hand closures as miken32 suggested. Personally I prefer Closures/short Closures. The duplication is not that big of a deal.

Comment: I've added the examples

Comment: Got it. Thanks @IGP!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function in which you will perform some check before eager loader message which are related to the thread like this

```
Thread::with(["messages" => function($query){
    $query->where("type_id", 3);
})->find(1);
```